# Convert long format text file from S3 to wide format CSV

Tags: python-3.x, csv, amazon-s3, format, text-files

I'm trying to parse a text file (which lives in an S3 bucket) in python3 so that I can utilize it for visualizations but I'm having trouble with converting the data into a wide format CSV.

I've tried to pivot the data using the pandas library but it does not effectively roll up the rows.

```
### AWS Credentials
aws_access_key_id = key_1
aws_secret_access_key = key_2
region = region

### Access Text file
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file)

### Create dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()), error_bad_lines=False, 
names='A', nrows=90)

### Remove row separators
df = df[~df.A.str.contains("=========")]

### Remove all leading and trailing spaces in strings
df['A'] = df['A'].str.strip()

### Separate column names and values
df = pd.DataFrame(df.A.str.split(' ',1).tolist(),columns['columns','values'])

### Pivot dataframe
df.pivot(columns='columns', values='values')
```

## The text file looks like the below:

==============================================================
column_1     value_1.1
column_2     value_2.1
column_3     value_3.1

==============================================================
column_1     value_1.2
column_2     value_2.2
column_3     value_3.2

==============================================================
column_1     value_1.3
column_2     value_2.3
column_3     value_3.3

==============================================================

## The desired output would be the following in a pandas data frame:

column_1     column_2     column_3
value_1.1    value_2.1    value_3.1
value_1.2    value_2.2    value_3.2
value_1.3    value_2.3    value_3.3

I apologize for poor formatting of my post but would appreciate any help. I understand I'm likely not using the most optimal library for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Dict = {}

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    l = line.strip().split(' ')
    print(l)

    if l[0] not in Dict.keys():

        Dict[l[0]] = list(l[1])

    else:

        Dict[l[0]].append(l[1])
```

df = pd.DataFrame(Dict)
df